# Word associations with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to reproduce this figure:

[image]

in `tikz-pgf`. Words and scores are the following:

```
word    score
know    0.01
project 0.01
reduce  0.01
value   0.01
zero    0.01
report  0.03
water   0.03
future  0.05
solutions   0.06
made    0.08
packaging   0.08
recycling   0.08
waste   0.09
recycled    0.16
pollution   0.27
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution without using neither `axis` environment nor an external file or a data block but just simple `foreach` loops.

[image: word scores graph]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=80cm]
        \draw[thick] (-0.01,0) -- (0.3,0) node[below=5mm,midway]{Scores};
        %\draw[very thin,gray!50] (0,0) grid[xstep=0.01] (0.3,15);
        \draw[very thin,gray] (0,0) grid[xstep=0.1] (0.3,15);
        \foreach \i in {0.0,0.1,0.2,0.3} \node[below] at (\i,0) {\strut \i};
        \foreach \word/\score [count=\i] in {
            know/0.01,
            project/0.01,
            reduce/0.01,
            value/0.01,
            zero/0.01,
            report/0.03,
            water/0.03,
            future/0.05,
            solutions/0.06,
            made/0.08,
            packaging/0.08,
            recycling/0.08,
            waste/0.09,
            recycled/0.16,
            pollution/0.27
            }
            {
            \node[left](\i) at (0,\i) {\word};
            \fill (\score,\i) circle(2pt);
            }
        \node[fit=(1)(15)](words){};
        \node[rotate=90,left=of words]{Words};

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```